# Как отключить масштабирование при изменении кластера меток в Яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты, масштабирование, кластеризация

Есть перечень меток (200шт), у каждой свой набор параметров.
При выборе фильтров на карте остаются только те метки, параметры которых совпадают  с фильтром.
Реализовано это путем очистки кластера и повторного наполнения отфильтрованными метками.
Каждый раз при применении фильтра происходит масштабирование карты - она масштабируется так, чтобы были видны все метки.

Проблема - если пользователь до применения фильтра ввел какой то адрес  в строку адреса самих карт и масштабировался к этой точке, а теперь хочет отфильтровать метки вокруг адреса, то карта масштабируется так, чтобы захватить все релевантные фильтру метки и повторный ввод в адресную строку уже не приближает к метке, приходится искать ее глазами на карте и приближаться, или сменить адрес на сторонний и снова на нужный.

Можно как-то отключить масштабирование при наполнении кластеризатора и размещении меток?
Или запретить масштабирование если пользователь поискал адрес? Как это сделать? помогите, пожалуйста...

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
var poi=[], adresses_new, adresses_new_names, properties_start_position,coordinates_position, coorddinates_new_array=[];


            function init() {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "W:\\maps\\maps_new.csv",
                    //url: "https://kb.rt.ru/Report_Library/maps_new.csv",
                    method: 'GET',
                    async:false,
                    success: function (data) {
                      adresses_new  = data.split("^.^");
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });

                adresses_new_names=adresses_new[0].split(';');
                adresses_new_names.pop();
                adresses_new.pop();
                adresses_new.shift();

                adresses_new.forEach(function(item,i,adresses_new){
                    adresses_new[i]=item.split(';')
                    adresses_new[i].pop();
                    })

                properties_start_position=adresses_new_names.indexOf('Комментарий')+1; 
                coordinates_position=adresses_new_names.indexOf('Координаты'); 
                adresses_new_names.forEach(function(item,i,adresses_new_names){
                    if(i>properties_start_position)
                        {
                        var sign_of_sameness=true, value_of_first_row=adresses_new[0][i];

                        adresses_new.forEach(function(row_item, row_i, adresses_new){
                            if(adresses_new_names[i]!='')
                                {
                                if(adresses_new[row_i][i]!=value_of_first_row)
                                    {
                                    sign_of_sameness=false;
                                    }   
                                }
                            }); 
                            if(item.indexOf('Для ЮЛ')>=0)
                                {
                                $('#services').append(' <span class="service ul_service">'+item+'</span>');
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                $('#services').append(' <span class="service">'+item+'</span>');   
                                }
                        }
                    })


                    adresses_new.forEach(function(item,i, adresses_new){
                        coorddinates_new_array[i]=[];
                        adresses_new[i][coordinates_position].split(',').forEach(function(coord_item, coord_i,item_of_sdresses_new){
                            coorddinates_new_array[i].push(coord_item.replace(/ /g,''));         
                            })
                        //get_coord(item[2]+','+item[3]+','+item[4],i);
                        });

                myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                        center: [55.76, 37.64],
                        zoom: 5
                    }, {
                        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
                    }),
                     clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
                        /**
                         * Через кластеризатор можно указать только стили кластеров,
                         * стили для меток нужно назначать каждой метке отдельно.
                         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/option.presetStorage.xml
                         */
                        preset: 'islands#invertedVioletClusterIcons',
                        /**
                         * Ставим true, если хотим кластеризовать только точки с одинаковыми координатами.
                         */
                        groupByCoordinates: false,
                        /**
                         * Опции кластеров указываем в кластеризаторе с префиксом "cluster".
                         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ClusterPlacemark.xml
                         */
                        clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
                        clusterHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
                        geoObjectHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
                    }),
                      /* getPointOptions = function () {
                        return {
                            preset: 'islands#violetIcon'
                        };
                    },*/
                    points = poi,
                    markersArray=poi,
                    geoObjects = [];

                /**
                 * Данные передаются вторым параметром в конструктор метки, опции - третьим.
                 * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.xml#constructor-summary
                 */
                /**
                 * Можно менять опции кластеризатора после создания.
                 */
                   lod(adresses_new,coorddinates_new_array);
                }



            function getPointData (index, target_array_adress, target_array_coords, schedule) {
                var adres_for_map, info_for_map;
                    adres_for_map = (target_array_adress[index][2] + ', ' + target_array_adress[index][3] + ', '+ target_array_adress[index][4]).replace(/"/g,''),
                    info_for_map = '<strong>Режим: </strong>'+ schedule.replace(/"/g,'')+'<br><br><strong> Как пройти: </strong>'+target_array_adress[index][10].replace(/"/g,'')+'<br><br><strong>Комментарий: </strong>'+target_array_adress[index][12].replace(/"/g,'');
                return {
                    balloonContentHeader: adres_for_map,
                    balloonContentBody:  info_for_map,
                    clusterCaption: adres_for_map
                };
            }
 function create_filter_points(){
                var filter=[];
                $('.checked').each(function(){
                    filter.push($(this).html())
                    });

                if(filter.length>0)
                    {
                    filter_array(filter);  
                    }
                else
                    {
                    lod(adresses_new,coorddinates_new_array);  
                    }
                }


            function lod(target_array_adress,target_array_coords){
                myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
                clusterer.removeAll();
                geoObjects=[];
                for(var i = 0, len = target_array_coords.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var resault_date='';
                    if(target_array_adress[i][9]!='')
                        {
                        var end_date=target_array_adress[i][8].split('.'), start_date=target_array_adress[i][7].split('.');
                        if(new Date() <= new Date(end_date[2], end_date[1]-1, end_date[0]) && new Date() >= new Date(start_date[2], start_date[1]-1, start_date[0]) )
                            {
                            resault_date='до '+target_array_adress[i][8]+' включительно: <br>'+ target_array_adress[i][9]+'<br>Далее: '+target_array_adress[i][6];
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            resault_date=target_array_adress[i][6];   
                            }
                        }
                    if(resault_date=='')
                        {
                        resault_date=target_array_adress[i][6];     
                        }
                    geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark(target_array_coords[i], getPointData(i,target_array_adress,target_array_coords,resault_date)/*, getPointOptions()*/);
                    }

                clusterer.options.set({
                    gridSize: 80,
                    clusterDisableClickZoom: true
                    });

                clusterer.add(geoObjects);
                myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
                myMap.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
                    checkZoomRange: true
                    });  
                }


            function filter_array(array_for_filter){
                if(array_for_filter[0]=='')
                    {
                    lod(adresses,poi);  
                    }
                else
                    {
                    resault_of_filter=[];
                    filtered_adresses=[];
                    coordinate=[];
                    array_of_filter_keys=[];

                    array_for_filter.forEach(function(item, i, array_for_filter){
                        adresses_new_names.forEach(function(name_item, name_i, adresses_new_names){
                            if(name_item==item)
                                {
                                array_of_filter_keys.push(name_i);   
                                }
                            });
                        });

                    adresses_new.forEach(function(adr,i,adresses_new){
                        var y=true

                        array_of_filter_keys.forEach(function(filter,n,array_for_filter){

                            if(adr[filter]=='нет' || adr[filter]=='')
                                {
                                y=false
                                }
                            });

                         if (y==true)
                            {
                            resault_of_filter[i]=adresses_new[i];
                            }
                        });

                    if(resault_of_filter.length>0)
                        {
                        resault_of_filter.forEach(function(item,i,resault_of_filter){
                            filtered_adresses.push(item);
                            coordinate.push(item[5].split(','))
                            })
                        lod(filtered_adresses,coordinate);     
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
                        clusterer.removeAll();
                        geoObjects=[];
                        }   
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Можно увидеть пример кода? Например, на jsfiddle.

Comment: @naivv, там много стороннего кода, дополнил вопрос кодом, который реализует формирование карты и вывод/обновление точек

Comment: Без списка точек (он недоступен) трудно понять, что не так в поведении кластеризатора. Кстати, значение gridSize должно быть равно 2^n (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer-docpage/#Clusterer__param-options.gridSize ).

Comment: В целом для фильтрации меток по параметрам можно использовать менеджер объектов (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/ ) и метод setFilter (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#method_detail__setFilter ).

В песочнице есть пример фильтрации и кластеризации: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter